# (Code Refactoring) shell command using child_process in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, sh

I am working on a nuxt.js / vue.js project and applying the atomic design methodology, it means that the components will be divided into and hundreds of components in each folder

```
/components
   /atoms
   /molecules
   /organisms
```

I want and need to import in a grouped and smart way, so i do:

in `webpack.config.js` or `nuxt.config.js`

using [Compiler Hooks](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/) from webpack for each build, generating an index.js exporting components

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

module.exports = {

  // ... other config here ...

  plugins: [

    // ... other plugins here ...

    {
        apply: compiler => {
          compiler.hooks.beforeCompile.tap('MyPlugin', compilation => {
            exec('sh assets/DynamicExport.sh', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
              if (stdout) process.stdout.write(stdout)
              if (stderr) process.stderr.write(stderr)
            })
          })
        }
      }
  ]
};
```

in `assets/DynamicExport.sh`

```
ls components/atoms/ | grep -v index.js | sed 's#^\([^.]*\).*$#export {default as \1} from "./&"#' > components/atoms/index.js

ls components/molecules/ | grep -v index.js | sed 's#^\([^.]*\).*$#export {default as \1} from "./&"#' > components/molecules/index.js

ls components/organisms/ | grep -v index.js | sed 's#^\([^.]*\).*$#export {default as \1} from "./&"#' > components/organisms/index.js
```

then an `index.js` file is generated in each folder by exporting all components of the folder

```
export { default as ButtonStyled } from './ButtonStyled.vue'
export { default as TextLead } from './TextLead.vue'
export { default as InputSearch } from './InputSearch.vue'
....
```

Finally i can import in a clear, grouped and smart way, 
anywhere in my application.

```
import {
    ButtonStyled,
    TextLead,
    InputSearch
} from '@/components/atoms'

import {
    SearchForm
} from '@/components/molecules'
```

everything works fine, however I'm finding the solution a bit big, calling a file in `assets`, maybe it has another way that I do not know ..

Is there any way to refactor and lower the content of `assets/DynamicExport.sh` something less repetitive?

Any code refactoring will be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this really a question? "Refactor my code" doesn't seem like a question. It's not clear what the parameters for a successful answer are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a shell file, so you can do something like this:

```
parameters=( atoms molecules organisms )
for item in ${parameters[*]}
do
  ls components/$item/ | grep -v index.js | sed 's#^\([^.]*\).*$#export {default as \1} from "./&"#' > components/$item/index.js
done
```

And if you wanted to be really sneaky, and you knew that every subdirectory in the components directory needed to be iterated, then you could even replace the first line with:

```
parameters=$(ls components)
```

---

**EDIT** parsing ls is not safe. Here is a better approach:

```
for item in components/*; 
do
  # do something with item
done
```

Comment: Downvoted because [parsing the output of ls is bad practise](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: If you refactor my code, that's enough to qualify as a successful response, I'm very grateful.

Comment: do you think you have some way to write a shell script for this function, straight into callback hooks?

Comment: @oguzismail, thanks for pointing that out. Updating my answer with something safer.